# How to make python "goto" a previous line to get more input?

Tags: python, if-statement, goto

So i understand goto is a very bad form of coding, however i need a program to go back to a previous line when the input is incorrect in console.

```
print ("You wake up.")
print ("You do what?")
seg1 = input()
if seg1 == ("Stand") or seg1 == ("stand") or seg1 == ("stand up") or seg1 == ("Stand up") or seg1 == ("Stand Up"):
    print ("You get up")
    print ("You look around you... your in a dark room. A door hangs slightly ajar infront of you.")
    print ("You do what?")
else:
    print ("I dont understand")
```

After the else statement has run i want it to repeat line 2 and continue with the program from there... how can i do this?

Comment: Maybe try a while statement?

Comment: Ref: [while statements](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/whilestatements.html)

Comment: True story: When I was a good bit younger and only knew BASICA, someone told me they wrote a whole program *without* any GOTOs. It blew my mind. (These days I'm glad to have all-but forgotten about GOTO.)

Comment: Sure. Using GOTO is a *bad* practice.

Comment: Try using this instead of your current if statement: `if seg1.lower() in ['stand up', 'stand']:`, it's functionally equivalent - just a little nicer to look at.

Comment: @dano I was going to say the same thing, but then I wondered how he could deal with the word "stand" being a part of other words. For example, if the user entered "I don't understand", that would be interpreted as "stand up". Any suggestions on how to get around that?

Comment: @crclayton Are you sure? `"I don't understand" in ['stand']` evaluates to `False` for me.

Comment: @crclayton I'd write or employ a mini-language parser and classifier, among other changes (like abstraction of locations/actions from the input loop) .. but that is getting much more complex.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Goto statements are typically used in very low level languages like assembly or basic. In higher level languages like python, they are abstracted out so they don't exist. The way you would want to do this is by using a loop(which is the abstraction of a goto statement). This can be achieved with the following code.

```
valid_input = False
while not valid_input:
    print ("You wake up.")
    print ("You do what?")
    seg1 = input()
    if seg1 == ("Stand") or seg1 == ("stand") or seg1 == ("stand up") or seg1 == ("Stand up") or seg1 == ("Stand Up"):
       print ("You get up")
       print ("You look around you... your in a dark room. A door hangs slightly ajar infront of you.")
       print ("You do what?")
       valid_input = True
   else:
       print ("I dont understand")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a `while` loop instead of a `goto`, like so:

```
print ("You wake up.")
print ("You do what?")
while True:
    seg1 = input()
    if seg1 == ("Stand") or seg1 == ("stand") or seg1 == ("stand up") or seg1 == ("Stand up") or seg1 == ("Stand Up"):
        print ("You get up")
        print ("You look around you... your in a dark room. A door hangs slightly ajar infront of you.")
        print ("You do what?")
        break
    else:
        print ("I dont understand")
```

What happens is that the `while` will loop supposedly forever, but in reality we will `break` out of it as soon as we get an input we like. That takes care of your issue.

A `goto` should never, ever be necessary in your code. There's pretty much always a way to restructure your program so it works without a `goto`, and it will probably work better as a result.